# How to delete Failed Jenkins Job in a way that build number count remain noneffective?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way by which i can delete failed Jenkins jobs and count becomes like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and not like 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 assuming that job number 3 has failed and thus deleted.

My case:
I deleted Red (Failed) Jenkins Job as i want 5 consecutive Jobs to be Green. Now when i build again, new Job is build with new build number as +1. So it is visible that some job has been deleted.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. I only know one way but it's rather hacky and the exact steps will depend on your version of jenkins, the operating system that it's hosted on and the way that jenkins was installed. I'm including the steps for a fairly typical jenkins 2.63 CentOS install as a proof of concept with the caveat that it's not really standard practice for someone to rewrite their build history.

The change would involve modifying the jenkins build configs directly on disk and then restarting/reloading jenkins. The install path is site-specific, but in this example it's /var/lib/jenkins
The directory layout will depend on your jenkins version, but in this example there's a jobs subdirectory which contains a separate directory for each jenkins job, eg:

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/
total 0
drwxr-x---. 5 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jul  3 08:37 jenkins_job_1
drwxr-x---. 5 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jul  3 08:37 jenkins_job_2
drwxr-x---. 5 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jul  3 08:37 jenkins_job_3
```

Inside the job directory there is a subdirectory containing the jenkins build history, symlinks to the most recent successful and unsuccessful builds, the xml containing the job configuration and a file showing the next build number:

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jenkins_job_1
total 16
drwxr-x---. 4 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jun 21 16:54 builds
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins 4146 Jun 21 12:28 config.xml
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins   22 Jun 21 16:29 lastStable -> builds/lastStableBuild
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins   26 Jun 21 16:29 lastSuccessful -> builds/lastSuccessfulBuild
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins    4 Jun 27 10:53 nextBuildNumber
```

The build runs themselves will look something like this:

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jenkins_job_1/builds/
total 0
drwxr-x---. 2 jenkins jenkins 78 Jun 29 10:13 1
drwxr-x---. 2 jenkins jenkins 78 Jun 29 10:13 2
drwxr-x---. 2 jenkins jenkins 78 Jun 29 10:14 3
drwxr-x---. 2 jenkins jenkins 78 Jun 29 10:38 4
drwxr-x---. 2 jenkins jenkins 78 Jun 29 11:51 5
drwxr-x---. 2 jenkins jenkins 78 Jun 29 13:11 6
drwxr-x---. 2 jenkins jenkins 78 Jun 29 13:21 7
drwxr-x---. 2 jenkins jenkins 78 Jun 29 13:41 8
drwxr-x---. 2 jenkins jenkins 78 Jun 29 13:50 9
drwxr-x---. 2 jenkins jenkins 78 Jun 29 13:55 10
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins  1 Jun 29 10:13 lastFailedBuild -> 2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins  2 Jul  5 09:46 lastStableBuild -> 10
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins  2 Jul  5 09:46 lastSuccessfulBuild -> 10
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins  2 Jun 29 08:17 lastUnstableBuild -> -1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 jenkins jenkins  1 Jun 29 10:13 lastUnsuccessfulBuild -> 2
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins  0 Jun 29 08:17 legacyIds
```

In order to edit the build history, the relevant build directory will need to be deleted, the subsequent build numbers will need to be decremented and the symlinks for the last failed, successful, unsuccessful, unstable and stable builds will need to be repointed where necessary. For example, if we choose to delete build 5, then builds 6-10 will need to be renamed and the relevant symlinks repointed:

```
$ rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jenkins_job_1/builds/5
$ for i in `seq 6 10`; do mv -i $i $(($i - 1)); done
$ ln -sf 9 lastStableBuild
$ ln -sf 9 lastSuccessfulBuild
```

Once all the relevant symlinks have been updated, you'll also need to decrement the nextBuildNumber:

```
echo 10 > /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jenkins_job_1/nextBuildNumber
```

Then either restart jenkins from the command line or "Manage Jenkins" option in the web interface and the changes to the job should be visible. Alternatively, you could try the "Reload Configuration from Disk" option in the jenkins web interface.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But as i'm new to Jenkins, this looks tough to me. I tried an option 'Set Build Name' under Build Environment section. It is a temporary solution as of now.